# What happened to the infant near the end of "Border"?

Tags: plot-explanation, border

In the Swedish movie *Border* (2018), the infant of Tina's befriended couple got hurt and they called an ambulance.

Is there an explanation for what happened there? The injuries looked quite strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_(2018_film)#Plot), "[the baby] has been replaced by the changeling (unbeknownst to her parents who believe the changeling is their actual child who is dying)"

So Vore switched the neighbour's baby for the "hiisi" he'd been keeping in the fridge.